# is there any java code for queue based on due date priority dispatching rule (EDD)? and how?

Tags: parameters, queue, jobs, priority-queue, event-dispatching

I need EDD priority rules java code
And I want to ask.

Here I have 2 agents namely WeldBolt and SPC PIN which have different process flows. Then the 2 agents go through the grooving process together so that the 2 agents will meet in 1 queue to enter the grooving process. Then I want to define a queue based on the priority delivery rule type EDD (due date), "for example, the WeldBolt agent due date is Monday, 1 February 2023, while the SPC agent pin due date is Tuesday, 2 February 2023". then after completing the grooving process for the 2 agents procees to the next process with a different path. Then what Java program code should I use? Do you know what the code looks like? would you like to give step by step what I have to do?

but here I have made 2 weld bolt agents and SPC pins that will run on these 2 paths. for priority rules I want it only after the washing process, not from the source (initial arrival).

you can see the picture I sent, so after the washing process there is 1 queue to enter the grooving process, then after the grooving process is complete the weldbolt agent will choose the path to the HT process while the SPC PIN agent chooses the path to the barrel vib process

I've also changed the FIFO rule in the queue to be a priority, but I'm confused about how it goes

I need answer all. Help me. Thankyou

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5InxP.png)

I have created 2 separate agents, and do I have to create 1 agent which contains 3 parameters? if so, I've tried creating a new agent which contains 3 types of parameters, namely Weldbolt, SPC and Due_Date. but for the type of value and the value it's confused what to fill in.

and I have also changed the queue element from fifo to priority based. after that I don't know what to do next? I need one answer

please look at the picture I sent
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOeto.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wA977.png)